# How to get (parse) this JSON in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Now I get POST data in JSON format like:

```
if ($request->filled('Countries')) {
    dd($request->Countries);
}
```

Where `$request->Countries` is array is sent from client:

```
"Countries": [2,15]
```

What if I want to send the following JSON format:

```
{
   "places": [{"country": 1, "city": 1}, {"country": 1, "city": 2}]
}
```

How to get this data using request in Laravel and handle it?

Comment: And how to validate this using default validator in Laravel?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For validation nested elements in JSON/Array must have to use this sintax:

```
$v = Validator::make($request->all(), [
  'person.*.id' => 'exists:users.id',
  'person.*.name' => 'required:string',
]);
```

For JSON object:

```
{"person": {"id": 1, "name": "OOO"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

use json_decode($json, true) to parse it to a PHP array:

```
$parsed_array = json_decode($data, true);
```

Comment: And how to validate these nested parameters?

Comment: I think we should not set the second param is true because it will parse all object structure to an array. The result will be [
   "places": [["country": 1, "city": 1] ["country": 1, "city": 2]]
] but not {
   "places": [{"country": 1, "city": 1}, {"country": 1, "city": 2}]
}

Answer (score 1):

just a tip. request()->input() method accepts dot notation which allows you to have unlimited nests. If you want to create a new request from a nested level of your request you could just

```
$r = $request->input('places');
$requests[] = new Illuminate\Http\Request($r);
```